# Center left <ul> in Bootstrap's navbar to fit the right one

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

My navbar looks as follows:

[image]

And I'd like to vertically center the left menu to fit the Github icon. I suppose a special class should be added to the left one. Here is the code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">

        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github fa-2x"></i></a></li>
                <!--here will be more icons-->
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</nav>
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Have you tried line-height ..?

Comment: It only increases overall size of navbar.

Comment: Can you add a fiddle .?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ego0u5rv/ Don't know why github icon doesn't apper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this as well; the `navbar-nav` line height is 20px by default so you can apply that to your icons to reduce their default line height(s). (The default line height for font awesome 2x is 28px I believe.)

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar {
    height: 50px;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-right i {
    line-height: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">About</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Skills</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Education</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github fa-1x"></i></a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github fa-2x"></i></a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github fa-3x"></i></a>

        </li>
        <!--here will be more icons-->
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: 4px is an arbitrary number, so when I change the icon from 2x to 4x it will not work, sure? Is there any way to just center the left ul menu?

Answer (score 1):

You can just align the nav items using padding

```
.navbar-nav a {
    padding: 6px 10px; /*Adjust values to suit*/
}
```

I would avoid using `line-height` to fix the alignment as it will cause the links to look strange if the words wrap.

Using padding on the `<a>` tag allows the area around the link to be clicked (not just the text itself)

Comment: It doesn't have any impact. Are you sure to use it on <a> on both left and right side of the nav?

Comment: The first value affects the padding on the top and bottom of the element, the second value affects the padding on the left and right of the element. Try `padding: 12px 10px` and see if it makes a difference